# How to capture Bluetooth Controller while Mac App is inactive?

Tags: bluetooth, controller, iokit, nimbus

I am attempting to write a small helper app for macOS that captures the input of a Nimbus Steel Series game controller and converts it to keyboard and mouse events for another application (a game that does not support controllers).

In my **first attempt** I used `GCController` but as soon as the app becomes inactive no more events are received from the controller. There seems to be no way to change this.

In my **second attempt** I used `CBCentralManager` to discover the controller, hoping I could work with it using standard Bluetooth services. But the controller does not even show up in a scan, either with the controller being connected or disconnected. I find devices around the house (iPads, iPhones, smart tv's, computers), but no peripheral that identifies itself as Nimbus. However, there are a couple `nil` peripherals which I suppose are auxiliary peripherals from Apple devices such as the Magic Mouse or the Wireless Keyboard.

In my **third attempt** I tried to make the main window an `NSPanel` in HUD style. The panel stays afloat but it still becomes inactive when I click elsewhere. No controller events received. I thought maybe I could show the panel above the fullscreen game in a corner somehow. But it still needs to be active to get `GCController` events, then the game would not get events.

Are there any other options to receive game controller inputs which the app is inactive?
Would it work via IOKit? I have been hesitant to use IOKit so far because I was hoping to resolve this issue without it, being a very lowlevel API.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the `IOHIDManager` functions. The callbacks receive events even if the app is not active.